# How can I fix ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python

I am writing the below mentioned simple code in Python, but it does not run and I am getting the mentioned error. Please let me know how to fix it.

```py
a, b = [int(x) for x in input("Enter the two numbers:").split()]
```

Error:

```
>ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-51ed8ee9b41b> in <module>
      1 #try:
----> 2 a,b=[int(x) for x in input("Enter the two numbers:").split()]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Using a list comprehension like this is fragile because it is much harder to guard against common input errors, such as forgetting to put a space between the numbers. Consider separating input from processing to make validating input easier.

Comment: @triple while it is the same error (and I believe this question should be closed...), I don't see how that link answers this question... It is about iterating a dict instead of its `items()` while here it's a simple matter of wrong input by the OP (which they doesn't share with us...)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for the feedback - yeah, the duplicate I picked was probably too far off. I selected a different one as the primary dupe target now, though it's probably still possible to find one which is even closer to the OP's.